# NativeScript Google Maps Api - Google Maps appearing too small

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript

I am writing an app with NativeScript v6 and Angular 8.

tns --version
6.1.2

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk) to try to display Google Maps.

The map appears and no errors are thrown but the map is too small and I can't see the markers.

[image: example screenshot]

Here is my code snippet:

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry';
import { MapView, Marker, Position } from "nativescript-google-maps-sdk";

import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";

// Important - must register MapView plugin in order to use in Angular templates
registerElement('MapView', () => MapView);
@component({
selector: "ns-clocking",
templateUrl: "./clocking.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./clocking.component.css"],
moduleId: module.id
})
export class ClockingComponent implements OnInit {

mapView: MapView;

constructor() {}

public ngOnInit() {}

public onMapReady(event) {
    console.log(" map ready ");

    const mapView = event.object;

    this.mapView = mapView;

    const NA_CENTER_LATITUDE = 39.8283459;
    const NA_CENTER_LONGITUDE = -98.5816737;

    this.mapView.latitude = NA_CENTER_LATITUDE;
    this.mapView.longitude = NA_CENTER_LONGITUDE;
    this.mapView.zoom = 3;

    const stLouisCoordinates = {
        latitude: 38.619081,
        longitude: -90.196846
    };

    const stLouisMarker = new Marker();
    stLouisMarker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(
        stLouisCoordinates.latitude,
        stLouisCoordinates.longitude
    );
    stLouisMarker.title = "St. Louis, MO";
    stLouisMarker.snippet = "Go Cardinals!";
    stLouisMarker.color = "#6B8E23";
    this.mapView.addMarker(stLouisMarker);

}
}
```

template:

```
<ScrollView>
    <Page class="page">
        <StackLayout>

            <Label class="h3" text="Maps"></Label>

            <GridLayout>
                <MapView
                    #mapView
                    i-padding="50,50,50,50"
                    (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
                    iosOverflowSafeArea="true">
                </MapView>
            </GridLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because you have MapView wrapped inside StackLayout. You will have to use a single GridLayout and allocate all space below label to MapView.

```
<Page class="page">
    <GridLayout rows="auto,*">
        <Label row="0" class="h3" text="Maps"></Label>
        <MapView row="1"
            #mapView
            i-padding="50,50,50,50"
            (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
            iosOverflowSafeArea="true">
        </MapView>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Between, you should use ScrollView only when it's necessary, mostly with in Page not above Page. Page is designed to be placed inside a Frame, totally for navigation purpose.

Learn more about layouts at https://www.nslayouts.com/

Comment: The map is bigger but it is blank and just grey.

Comment: That's not an issue related to the OP, I guess you must be missing the key or using wrong certificate to build the app than the one you configured in dev console.

Comment: I have a key that I generated from the google console.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to look at Android Device Monitor for error logs, you might get a clear picture of what's going wrong. Remember, maps do not work on Emulator, it needs a device.

Comment: I am testing on a real device. I made a new question for this issue.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I face a similar issue